# Variable Separable Form for $\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{t^3+r^3}{t^2r+tr^2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I just need a hint or a method on how to separate the equation 
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{t^3+R^3}{t^2R+tR^2}$$
so I can integrate it and get a general solution in terms of $R(t)$

Comment: Is $r$ a constant?

Comment: all r's were supposed to be uppercase in the right hand side my bad

Comment: $t$ cannot be constant. You're taking a derivative with respect to it..

Comment: R and t are variables****

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{t^3+R^3}{t^2R+tR^2}$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{(t^2-tR+R^2)}{tR}$$
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\dfrac tR-1+\dfrac Rt$$
It's homogeneous. $R=ut \implies R'=u't+u$
$$u't+u=\dfrac 1u-1+u$$
$$u't=\dfrac 1u-1$$
It's separable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v=\frac{R}{t}\Rightarrow R=vt$ . Then, differentiating both sides of this equation w.r.t. t, we get, $$\frac{dR}{dt}=v+t\frac{dv}{dt}$$ Now, dividing the numerator and denominator of the right hand side of the given differential equation, we get,

$$\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{1+\displaystyle{\frac{R^3}{t^3}}}{\displaystyle{\frac{R}{t}+\frac{R^2}{t^2}}}=\frac{1+v^3}{v+v^2}\Rightarrow v+t\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{1+v^3}{v+v^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow t\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{1+v^3}{v+v^2}-v=\frac{1-v^2}{v+v^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{v+v^2}{1-v^2}dv=\frac{dt}{t}$$ And so the equation becomes separable in $v$ and $x$.

Comment: I was stuck with this questions for hours my maths is trash and needed help thank you so much

Comment: Such equations are homogeneous equations. Whenever you encounter a homogeneous differential equation use the above substitution to make it separable.